# CSS Hover-Effect isn't working in Firefox because of "display: inline;"

Tags: html, css, firefox, animation, hover

I've got a problem with the navigation of my website. There's a button defined with "display: inline;", because otherwise the buttons wouldn't appear horizontal to each other.

Then I have a animation, a hover effect. There it has to be "display: inline-block;", because Firefox wouldn't play the animation without that.

The problem is that I've defined "display: inline;" first, so Firefox just ignores "display: inline-block;" and the animation doesn't play. The problem is only in Firefox, not in Chrome and not even in IE.

So here's the HTML-code:

```
 <div id="nav">
  <a href="projekte.html"><li class="sweep">PROJECTS</li></a>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
#nav {
    float: right;
    width: auto;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 12px 10px 0px 0px;
}

#nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}

#nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #3a96d3;
}

.sweep {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition-property: color;
    transition-property: color;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.sweep:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #3a96d3;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -webkit-transition-property: transform;
    transition-property: transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}   

.sweep:hover, .hvr-sweep-to-top:focus, .hvr-sweep-to-top:active {
    color: white;
}

.sweep:hover:before, .hvr-sweep-to-top:focus:before, .hvr-sweep-to-top:active:before {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It shouldn't make a difference if you set `#nav  li` also to `display: inline-block;`

Comment: Thank you, I think I just worked with a too old version of Firefox